# LinearLayout or tablelayout for periodic table?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to build an android app periodic table , i'm trying to achive something like that in picture : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZysS.png

First I thought to use table layout but I found out that isn't the best way , so I choose to go with linear layout , so first I made a vertical linearlayout (parent) , then for every row i made a horizontal linarlayout , and within that linarlayout another vertical linearlayout with two text view element name and element atomic number.

So my xml file is getting pretty long and I think it's consuming a little time to render ( since there are 118 elements ).
Is another way i can make it programmatically generate 118 elements ?
Or is this just the wrong way i've chosen ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `GridView` - but that's really for situations with dynamic content, where the rows and columns could change.

The rendering time for 118 layouts should not be that big of a deal. The issue is that you are probably rendering views that aren't visible. Something like a `GridView` will prevent that, along with allowing you to recycle/reuse views.

Comment: Does the grid view support such kind of layouting what user need? I don't think so